# Extract text after last occurrence of comma in hive

Tags: sql, csv, hive, substring, hiveql

I want to extract everything after last comma

```
abc,xyz,tuv
abc,123,abc,def
```

I want the result as

```
tuv
def
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regexp_extract:

```
regexp_extract(col,',([^,]+)$',1)
```

Using split:

```
split(col,',')[size(split(col,','))-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls use

```
substr(col,-1*instr(col,',',-1)+1)
```

So here instr will find position of comma from end of string. Then substring will pick that many string from end.